# How to get specific file path name using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, nodes

Is this even possible to get specific file path from url

my file path is like

```
testing\abc\pqr\subfolder1\anotherFolder

or

testing\sufolder\anothersubfolder\abc\pqr\xyz\mno
```

my output will look like this

```
testing\abc\pqr

or
testing\sufolder\anothersubfolder\abc
```

Its should remove last few name of a folder and provide only specific length folder name from the start of the path which I will pass in an array

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here.  Please try to describe in more detail what problem you're asking for help with.

Comment: i just want starting 3 or 4 file path name and discard rest of name from last @jfriend00

Comment: I don't understand what "starting 3 or 4 file path name" means.  You are just not communicating clearly what the problem is.  Can't help when we don't understand.

Comment: starting 3 or 4 file path name means 
/home/aakash/work/projectTest/root/pdf/secure.pdf

then I only need 
/home/aakash/work/projectTest/

and discard rest of the path @jfriend00

Comment: So, which is it?  3 or 4?

Comment: depends what i am passing in condition @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the path and just grab the number of segments you want from the front.  Since you're showing Windows-style paths, here's some sample code that uses the Windows path separator.  This can be adapted to use [path.sep](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep) if you want a cross platform version.  Since your example paths do not start with a leading slash, this code assumes that.

```js
function getFrontPathSegments(fullPath, numSegments) {
    let pieces = fullPath.split("\\");
    return pieces.slice(0, numSegments).join("\\");
}


// example usage
let front = getFrontPathSegments("testing\\sufolder\\anothersubfolder\\abc\\pqr\\xyz\\mno", 3);
console.log(front);
```